# Why docker-compose needs compose file for exec command?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a bash script which located above directory in which docker-compose.yaml presents.

Inside bash script there is command:

```
docker-compose exec ${service} /somescript_inside_container.sh
```

When executing this bash script I'm getting:

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

But when running this command with docker and referencing `container_name` instead of `service` e.g.

```
docker exec ${container_name} /somescript_inside_container.sh
```

It will work.

For me it's not obvious behavior and I'm curious why is there such difference between docker and docker-compose ?

Comment: Those 2 commands should behave the same. Is there any chance you are experiencing something similar to this https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1012 ?
Also, try to explicitly specify the docker-compose file to see if it helps 

` docker-compose -f ${file_path} exec ${service} /somescript_inside_container.sh `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker container name that is created by docker compose  has a generated name, unless you specify the `container_name` property explicity.

Thus if you don't specify the compose file, the exec command has no idea which container it needs to exec into.

Moreover, the syntax for exec is:

```
exec [options] SERVICE COMMAND [ARGS...]
```

Thus you need to specify the service name, and you might have multiple compose files each using the same service name. Therefore, unless you specify the compose file, docker cannot choose the container in which the command needs to be ran into.

In the case of the docker exec command, you are explicitly specifying the container name. Thus there is no ambiguity.

On the other hand, in docker compose the service name is usually the meaningful portion of the config, and since the container name is autogenerated, explicitly specifying the container name will require manually looking up this generated name, unless you specify the compose file where the container was created from and docker compose can deduce back the container name.